# A controller can have fields/atributes/properties in mvc architecture?

Tags: model-view-controller

A controller can have fields/artributes/properties in mvc architecture? after Reading this article http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/model-view-controller-explained/  I have the idea that it receives the inputs of the user in the application and then is like a bridge with models and views but what is exactly a controller in mvc? is a normal class that can have fields and methods like other classes? if yes for what could serve those atributes or fields? (in general mvc architecture, not speaking about a specific framework like asp.net mvc or spring mvc etc. )

Comment: As mention in my question I've already read in google articles and examples but not so clear about it.sorry I'm new in programming. and this a question so important that should have an answer in stackoverflow.

Comment: Well it is hard to answer it if you don't want it for a specific framework since it varies with language/framework what you will need. That is why you should search for more examples and look at a few so you can compare languages/frameworks and learn what a controller is/need.

Comment: ok but I think maybe you know if a controller in some case(any mvc framework you have used) can have fields or atributtes besides methods and what would they serve? if you know that i'd thank your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about what the class specifically looks like, you should take a look at one mvc framework.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello";
   }

}
```

Basically, it is a normal class that will do the logic.
This piece of code of taken from here, you can take a look at the whole thing:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm

Comment: Ok, all controllers I've seen and created (I'm new in programming)controllers are full of methods, but then controller also can have atributes or fields? fields would serve for something in a controller?

Comment: They have fields and it really depends on how you want to do it all. Spring is a dependency project and you want to use controller as a singleton. Fields may be serving for accessing DB or other components.